# How can I ask for reward after mining?

Tags: python

Let's assume that I found the nonce for the block the world try to mine now. How can I say in python that this is the nonce and this is my wallet address so transfer the reward to it?!

Note: This question has nothing to do with the question: [How is a “reward” encoded in a block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68282)
I asked about the program that its inputs are the nonce and the wallet address.

Comment: Yes, that linked question gives the answer. You don't ask anyone to transfer the reward to your address. You do that yourself in the block you create, before you even start mining.

Comment: The program whose inputs are the nonce and the wallet address encodes the reward in the block so that if you mine the block you get the reward.